# How to invoke eTapestry API

Tags: api

I need information / Sample examples about eTapestry API.

Thanks,
Koustubh

Answer (score 2):

The primary documentation for the eTapestry API (including code samples) can be found at http://www.etapestry.com/files/api/home.html. You'll need a sandbox account from https://atl.etapestry.com/prod/APIWebOrder.jsp in order to have a system to test your code against.

Answer (score 0):

For better understanding of eTapestry API please visit :
[http://www.etapestry.com/files/api/home.html](http://www.etapestry.com/files/api/home.html.)

Sample code for Login Method:

```
require("lib/utils.php");
require("lib/nusoap.php");

// Set login details and initial endpoint
$loginId = "INPUT_LOGIN_ID";
$password = "INPUT_PASSWORD";
$endpoint = "https://sna.etapestry.com/v2messaging/service?WSDL";

// Instantiate nusoap_client
echo "Establishing NuSoap Client...";
$nsc = new nusoap_client($endpoint, true);
echo "Done";

// Did an error occur?
checkStatus($nsc);

// Invoke login method
echo "Calling login method...";
$newEndpoint = $nsc->call("login", array($loginId, $password));
echo "Done";

// Did a soap fault occur?
checkStatus($nsc);

// Determine if the login method returned a value
if ($newEndpoint != "")
{
  echo "New Endpoint: $newEndpoint";

  // Instantiate nusoap_client with different endpoint
  echo "Establishing NuSoap Client with new endpoint...";
  $nsc = new nusoap_client($newEndpoint, true);
  echo "Done";

  // Did an error occur?
  checkStatus($nsc);

  // Invoke login method
  echo "Calling login method...";
  $nsc->call("login", array($loginId, $password));
  echo "Done";

  // Did a soap fault occur?
  checkStatus($nsc);
}
// Output results
echo "Login Successful";

// Call logout method
stopEtapestrySession($nsc);
```

Comment: The lib/utils.php with functions like checkStatus isn't included anywhere?